# JQuery: Fade in after fading out multiple objects results in flicker

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, promise

For this project, I have a box (div), with some static content (including tabs) and content which can change under a variety of conditions (click, hover, and timer). Each of these dynamic content views lies in a separate div.

I'm trying to write a function that can handle all of these cases, including the initial load of the page, since all dynamic content is initially hidden with css. This function takes the parent box, which must be modified to keep track of things, and the view I wish to change to.

So, I first fade all the views out, to make sure nothing's there, and fade the new view in. I realised pretty soon that the callback wasn't working as ordered, so I ran across the promise() function. Unfortunately, this produces flickering in every browser I've tried (IE, Chrome, and Firefox). In Chrome, it was only every so often, but in the others it's just about constant.

```
$(container).children('.content_view').fadeOut(transition);
$(container).children('.content_view').promise().done(function() {
    $(next).fadeIn(transition);
});
```

That's the business end of my code at the moment. Is there a better way to do this, or some way to eliminate the flicker? Unfortunately, this page will mostly be viewed in the misbehaving browsers.

After playing around with delays, I suspect that the issue is a timing one. The premature removal of an element, or appearance of another, causes my layout to change momentarily until the final layout is reached. I suspect the promise() function implements such a delay.

EDIT:

I found a solution that seems to work well for me. Since my initial fade out was intended to handle the event that multiple views had somehow become unhidden (which was happening a lot for other reasons, use mouseenter and mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout) I decided it would be better to try to just immediately kill anything that's in the process of fading from a previous call, then do my regular fading:

```
$(container).children('.content_view').filter(function(){return ($(this).css('opacity') < 1)}).each(function() {
    $(this).stop();
    $(this).css('opacity',0);
    $(this).css('hidden','none');
});

if ($(container).children('.content_view').filter(function(){return ($(this).css('display') != 'none');}).length > 0)
    $(container).children('.content_view').filter(function(){return ($this.css('display') != 'none';}).fadeOut(transition, function() {
    $(content).fadeIn(transition);
});
else
    $(content).fadeIn(transition);
```

Hope that makes sense. I didn't know about the filter function before. Quite handy :)

Note that in my case, this works because this is the only way that any of the content gets swapped, and it will only leave one element tree fully visible (or getting there) at the end of each call. If that has not finished revealing by the next one, it gets killed immediately and replaced.

Comment: Could you put together a JSFiddle that replicates this?

Comment: I'm trying. Oh dear. Seems to be crashing a lot :P

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$(container).children('.content_view').fadeOut(transition, function() {
    $(next).fadeIn(transition);
});
```

then try:

```
$(container).children('.content_view').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(transition, function() {
        $(next).fadeIn(transition);
    });
});
```

However probably the nicest solution would be to use CSS transitions. Is that a possibility? On what browser does this have to work?

Comment: That was my first thought, but since the selector matches multiple elements, the callback function is executed immediately.

Comment: ok I added some other thing. which selector is the problem? .content_view or $(next)?

Comment: $(next) is just the object I pass in. It represents the root element I wish to insert. That element is of class content_view, as are all other views I can choose between.

The second solution here results in an odd flashing effect which overlaps with an initial fade. The third does the same but seems to leave content views there I never asked for. I assume next() moves to the next sibling node? That could be causing this behaviour

Comment: right, leave the .next() solution, it's just because I wasn't sure what is next

Comment: I did attempt to animate this before, but it never quite worked. According to the documentation, in the case that it is run on multiple elements, the callback will be called once for each of them. So, won't I wind up with a flashing effect as before?

I will attempt it tomorrow and let you know regardless.